# How do I use PHP CLI on Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I downloaded Eclipse PDT and it can only run PHP files on a web server (which outputs "Connection error").
I want to develop PHP CLI with Eclipse without a server, is that possible?

Comment: this is an application question not a programming one.

Comment: This is about programming and therefore is on-topic.